# android JSONArray length

Tags: android, arrays, logging

i have an array from a json feed i know that in the  jArray there is one league but i need to work out the count of that array incase a second is added to the feed at a later date. at the moment log cat isn't logging out "teamFeedStructure" does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or know how to correctly turn the length of an array into a string that i can use in an intent?

heres the code

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");                      
JSONArray jArray = objData.getJSONArray("structure");
//String leagues = jArray.toString();
//Log.v("myapp", "structure" + leagues);
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {    
     JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     leaguecountArray = oneObject.getJSONArray("league_id");
     for (int l=0; l < leaguecountArray.length(); l++) {     
         if (leaguecountArray.length() == 1) {
             teamFeedStructure = "One";
         }
         if (leaguecountArray.length() == 2) {
              teamFeedStructure = "Two";
         }
         Log.v("myapp", teamFeedStructure);  
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to iterate here:

```
for (int l=0; l < leaguecountArray.length(); l++)
{    
    if (leaguecountArray.length() == 1){

         teamFeedStructure = "One";
    }
    if (leaguecountArray.length() == 2){

        teamFeedStructure = "Two";
    }
    Log.v("myapp", teamFeedStructure);   
 }
```

Nevermind how many passes you do the result will still be the same.

Also you can use not English words, but `String` holding the number you need. Do like that:

```
teamFeedStructure = String.valueOf(leaguecountArray.length());
```

Then the value will become `"2"` for example. In your other activity you can parse it again to integer like that: `int number = Integer.parseInt(teamFeedStructure);`

Comment: its not logging out anything i have the tag set up right just confused as to why it wouldn't be logging it

Comment: Are you sure you are observing verbose level including? Also no logging will happen if your array is empty. Log the length of the array to see if it is really empty

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line

```
 teamFeedStructure = "greater two";
```

before

```
 if (leaguecountArray.length() == 1){
```

If you get **greater two** message, means your array length more than two.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone i discovered that i had gone a step too far into the feed which is why i was not getting anything in Logcat. now it's counting fine.

Comment: If this was the solution to the problem, you should mark it as 'accepted' using the tickmark next to the question. If you solved it using one of the other two posters' answers, you should accept their answer instead.